# Best solution for Phaser 3 pathfinding?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, path-finding

I have a game and I want to be able to have enemies pathfind to the player across a tilemap, is there a way to do this without programming my own a* algorithm? I've seen a couple supposedly still updated libraries for this, but neither of which have worked, they have both been broken with npm and not worked when added as a script. 
 The libraries I've tried are [Easystar](https://easystarjs.com/) and [Navmesh](https://github.com/mikewesthad/navmesh#phaser-navmesh-api-reference).

Any suggestions would be great, and while Phaser support would be useful, pathfinding over a 2D array would still be a good solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried it myself *(until now)*, but https://github.com/mikewesthad/navmesh is a great plugin and is very extensive.

> *... A JS plugin for fast pathfinding using navigation meshes, with optional wrappers for the Phaser v2 and Phaser v3 game engines. ...*

**p.s.:** on this page you can find a list of available plugins for phaser https://phaserplugins.com/

**Update:**

After testing in on an simple an example it worked fine, just be careful not to miss any steps.

Here the steps needed:

1. get the latest plugin file `phaser-navmesh-plugin.js` (currently from https://github.com/mikewesthad/navmesh/releases/tag/2.1.0)
2. load it from the html file
   `<script src="phaser-navmesh-plugin.js"></script>`
3. configure the plugin, in the `config`  (there are other ways but this is the more convinient)

   ```
    var config = {
        ...
        plugins: {
            scene: [
                {
                    key: "PhaserNavMeshPlugin", // Key to store the plugin class under in cache
                    plugin: PhaserNavMeshPlugin, // Class that constructs plugins
                    mapping: "navMeshPlugin", // Property mapping to use for the scene, e.g. this.navMeshPlugin
                    start: true
                }
            ]
        },
        scene: {
           ...
        }
    };
   ```
4. setup the map and the layer which should collide:

   ```
        var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: [[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]], tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
        var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tile01');
        var layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);

        // this is important, can also be multiple indices
        layer.setCollision(1);
   ```
5. create navMesh, pass the map and the created layer with should have to collisions.

   ```
        const navMesh = this.navMeshPlugin.buildMeshFromTilemap("mesh", map, [layer]);
   ```
6. when needed execute pathfinding *(x/y positions are in pixels, not tilesId)*:

   ```
        const path = navMesh.findPath({ x: 4, y: 4 }, { x: 17, y: 4 });
   ```

> You can load the plugin in also in the `preload` function like this

```
        this.load.scenePlugin({
            key: 'PhaserNavMeshPlugin',
            url: PhaserNavMeshPlugin,
            sceneKey: 'navMeshPlugin'
        });
```

**Here the demo code with a mini path trace when done:**

```
    var config = {
        scene: {
            preload,
            create,
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload() {
        this.load.image('tile01', 'tile01.png');
        this.load.scenePlugin({
            key: 'PhaserNavMeshPlugin',
            url: PhaserNavMeshPlugin,
            sceneKey: 'navMeshPlugin'
        });
    }

    function create() {
        var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: [[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]], tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
        var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tile01');
        var layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);

        layer.setCollision(1);

        const navMesh = this.navMeshPlugin.buildMeshFromTilemap("mesh", map, [layer]);
        const path = navMesh.findPath({ x: 4, y: 4 }, { x: 17, y: 4 });

        if (!path) {
            return;
        }

        let graphics = this.add.graphics();

        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000, 1);
        graphics.beginPath();
        graphics.moveTo(path[0].x, path[0].y);

        for (let idx = 1; idx < path.length; idx++) {
            graphics.lineTo(path[idx].x, path[idx].y);
        }

        graphics.strokePath();
    }
```

Comment: That navmesh plugin is one of the ones I listed that didn't work.

Comment: @MrToenails sorry my bad over read that part.

Comment: It's OK, it seems like that one would be a pretty good fit, and if you're willing to help it would be great to get some advice to try and get that working from someone who knows more about the working of Phaser.

Comment: @MrToenails I will look at it. btw. I updated my answer with a link to code of a very crude pathfinding implementation, maybe it helps.

Comment: The Glitch project is https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glistening-checkered-mice?path=scripts The navmesh is added as a script in scripts/general/phaser-navmesh-plugin.js, and the game confing is scripts/general/script.js. I added the navmesh at scripts/generation/rooms/camp.js on line 291. Let me know if i should add you as an editor.

Comment: @MrToenails I tested this with tiled and array map it works pretty well. I hope this helps you abit.

Comment: I'm not using tiled, the game is procedurally generated, which means I also need to add it as a global plugin since the scenes are added later.

Comment: @MrToenails I think the Plugin just can run on scene level, so just load the plugin in the `preload` function of the scenes. I updated my answer with this alternative

Comment: @MrToenails btw.: the examples were all done specifically without Tiled